# Do contractions with Dirac matrices involve a metric?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, metric-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

When figuring out where the spacetime metric enters an equation it is often useful to write all vector indices as covariant indices and write out the inverse metrics that are needed to contract them, as in the expression
$$ D_\mu \phi D^\mu \phi = g^{\mu \nu} D_\mu \phi D_\nu \phi.$$
Does such an inverse metric appear in the contraction of gamma matrices in a general background, i.e. expressions such as
$$ \bar \psi \, \gamma^\mu D_\mu \psi?$$

Comment: I posted the question and the answer I got myself to double-check. If anyone has a different interpretation, please write an answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, instead of the metric, the [Vierbein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_%28physics%29) enters, pulling back the gamma matrix, defined in the usual way in the tangent space, to the spacetime manifold.
$$ \bar \psi \, \gamma^\mu D_\mu \psi = \bar \psi \, \gamma^\alpha {e^\mu}_\alpha D_\mu \psi$$
This can be considered as the insertion of "half a metric", if one wishes. The Vierbein captures the characteristics of the background, i.e. spacetime dynamics or a static deviation from flat space.

Comment: You're almost correct. The partial derivative $\partial_\mu$ is also elevated to a covariant derivative acting on spinors. In particular $\nabla_\mu \psi_a = \partial_\mu \psi_a - \omega_\mu{}_a{}^b \psi_b$ where $\omega$ is the spin-connection. Also, "half a metric" is misleading. It's more like the "square root of the metric".

Comment: @Prahar A very good comment, I shall fix my equations.